# Powershell - Invoke-WmiMethod to create a Sharefolder remotely with full controle permission

Tags: powershell, wmi, share

I've been using this script to create my users folders but I just find that the remote share folder is created with ReadOnly share.

My question is how can I create the share folder with `$domainname\domain` users with `full control`?

```
Invoke-WmiMethod -Class win32_share -name Create -ArgumentList `
 @($null,"",100,"hideshare$","",e:\users\hideshare,0) -computername "DestinationSRV"
```

I've found many threads with answers but not with the method I use.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
#Username/Group to give permissions to
$trustee = ([wmiclass]'Win32_trustee').psbase.CreateInstance()
$trustee.Domain = "domainname"
$trustee.Name = "username or groupname"

#Accessmask values
$fullcontrol = 2032127
$change = 1245631
$read = 1179785

#Create access-list
$ace = ([wmiclass]'Win32_ACE').psbase.CreateInstance()
$ace.AccessMask = $fullcontrol
$ace.AceFlags = 3
$ace.AceType = 0
$ace.Trustee = $trustee

#Securitydescriptor containting access
$sd = ([wmiclass]'Win32_SecurityDescriptor').psbase.CreateInstance()
$sd.ControlFlags = 4
$sd.DACL = $ace
$sd.group = $trustee
$sd.owner = $trustee

$share = Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -List -ComputerName "DestinationSRV"
$share.create("e:\users\hideshare", "hideshare$", 0, 100, "Description", "", $sd)
```

The security for this share will only allow the specified username. You need to modify this(add multiple ace's) to add different groups, add everyone etc..

[Source for access-part](http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/powershell/setting-permissions/)

Comment: fyi: this only creates a share object with share rights. ntfs rights for the folder is another thing. And to take some best-practice into this when it comes to server admin. In most cases you would like to allow everyone full share access, and lock it down on ntfs(folder/file) level instead. The most restrictive of the two(share and ntfs rights) are the one that's used. So blocked in share rights + allowed ntfs = blocked from retmote location, and allowed locally on server. allowed in share + blocked in ntfs = block remote and local. so if possible, use ntfs to block access. easier to maintian

Comment: Ok I just finished my test and I receive an error:   
Invoke-WmiMethod : Invalid operation 
'At line:1 char:17
+ Invoke-WmiMethod <<<<  -Class win32_share -name Create -ArgumentList @($sd,"",100,"$USERNAME$","",$sharelocalpath,0) -computername $DESTINATION
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-WmiMethod], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWmiMethod'

Comment: thanks for the Tips on the NTFS right I call an other PS function and this part work fine.

Comment: If I replace the $sd by $null the script work fine any though ?

Comment: sure, I put my domain, and my username let me try again on a local path

Comment: I get the same result on local path when I remove the -computername

Comment: the problem only occours using invoke-wmimethod, don't know why. it works on w8 but not on w7 :S I've updated the answer to use an alternative, but I cannot confirm that it works remotely so please try it. if it doesn't work, we'll pack it inside an invoke-command to remote-execute

Comment: great it worked. The Remote share has been created perfectly. Thanks for your support

Comment: you're welcome. now I just need some help to understand why invoke-wmimethod didn't work on w7 :)