# How do I assign full access to a Windows Share using PowerShell 2

Tags: powershell, wmi

I have a simple PowerShell command that can share a folder:

```
$(Get-WMIObject Win32_Share -List).Create("C:\MyPath\WebData", "WebData", 0)
```

But that creates it with "Everyone" having read-only access.

How do I create it with everyone having full access? Or any other access, for that matter.

I can't work out how to use the `Win32_SecurityDescriptor` parameter on the WMI Share Create method.

The examples I have found so far only affect the file permissions (Get-ACL, Set-ACL, etc), which is *not* the problem I have, or they use command-line commands or vba,  which I also want to avoid. This must be possible in PS.

I cannot use PowerShell 3 here, so the new New-SMBShare and related methods are not available.

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've answered a similar question before:

[Powershell - Invoke-WmiMethod to create a Sharefolder remotely with full controle permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345972/powershell-invoke-wmimethod-to-create-a-sharefolder-remotely-with-full-control/14346750#14346750)

To make the rule apply for `Everyone` then it seems you need to modify it with:

```
$trustee.Name = "EVERYONE"
$trustee.Domain = $Null
```

[Source for Everyone-part](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/6aa558a6-f8b4-4cb5-bbb3-76eec9805681/powershell-remote-server-set-share-permissions-to-everyone-full-control?forum=ITCG)

Tested sample:

```
#Username/Group to give permissions to
$trustee = ([wmiclass]'Win32_trustee').psbase.CreateInstance()
$trustee.Domain = $null
$trustee.Name = "EVERYONE"

#Accessmask values
$fullcontrol = 2032127
$change = 1245631
$read = 1179785

#Create access-list
$ace = ([wmiclass]'Win32_ACE').psbase.CreateInstance()
$ace.AccessMask = $fullcontrol
$ace.AceFlags = 3
$ace.AceType = 0
$ace.Trustee = $trustee

#Securitydescriptor containting access
$sd = ([wmiclass]'Win32_SecurityDescriptor').psbase.CreateInstance()
$sd.ControlFlags = 4
$sd.DACL = $ace
$sd.group = $trustee
$sd.owner = $trustee

$share = Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -List
$share.create("d:\testfolder", "testshare$", 0, 100, "Description", "", $sd)
```